# Executing list of C# functions with variable parameters and return types

Tags: c#

Trying to use C#'s Action / Func functionality to execute a list of methods with various parameters. Here is some sample code (that does not compile) that illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Action> actions = getRelevantRules();
            foreach (Action a in actions)
            {
                String result = a.Invoke();
                Console.WriteLine("Got.." + result);
            }
        }

        public static List<Action> getRelevantRules()
        {
            List<Action> relevant = new List<Action>();

            relevant.Add(ruleCombintIt("Str1","Str2"));
            relevant.Add(ruleEchoIt("Str1"));
            relevant.Add(ruleChangeCase("Str1",true));

            return relevant;
        }

        public static String ruleEchoIt(String val)
        {
            return val;
        }

        public static String ruleChangeCase(String val, Boolean toUpper)
        {
            return (toUpper) ? val.ToUpper() : val.ToLower();
        }

        public static String ruleCombintIt(String val1, String val2)
        {
            return val1 + val2;
        }
    }
```

I know that the "Action" cannot be used as it does not return a result. However, I do need to be able to return the result. I have tried (without success to see how I could achieve this using Func and Delegate)

Key requirements:
1) Need to be able to get the String return value
2) Need to be able to set the actual parameter values of the function at the time I add the item to the list.
3) Need to be able to handle cases (as shown) where each method being added to the list may have different parameters.

Can what I am looking to do be done?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Feels a little awkward, but how about using a State-Object which will be modified by Actions? I mean you would have for example a class with Properties Arg1, Arg2, Arg3 ... You create an instance of this class and have your rules work on that (`a.Invoke(stateObj)`). Each Action would take a StateObj and work on the relevant properties.

Comment: Out of interest if you know the parameters and the method in `getRelevantRules` why do you want to defer it using an action rather than just executing it there (as you actually are now)?

Comment: Hi, within the "getRelevantRules" section, I am explicitly adding the various methods that I want to run. Because this is explicit, I know what parameters each require. As regards the return type, it can be assumed that every method returns the same return type (eg: in this case, a string).

Comment: @Chris, reason is because the execution needs to be abstracted from the user. Specifically, there is a base class that does the execution in a private method. The only thing the derived class is able to do is say which rules should be executed. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Fildor, not sure if I understand what you are proposing. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Maybe that's not necessary. Do the single "Rules" rely on the result of the previously executed rule? I.e. Rule2 needs take into account result of Rule1?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have rules without determined results and an optional length of parameters and want those to be executed by a method that is expected to do what with the unknown return type and pass what attributes to the unknown length method?

Comment: if the parameters are known way in advance to the execution of the methods, why don't you simply store the resulting values ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want is a `List<Func<string>>` - a `Func<string>` takes no arguments and returns a string.

Working code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Func<string>> actions = getRelevantRules();
        foreach (var a in actions)
        {
            String result = a();
            Console.WriteLine("Got.." + result);
        }
    }

    public static List<Func<string>> getRelevantRules()
    {
        List<Func<string>> relevant = new List<Func<string>>();

        relevant.Add(() => ruleCombintIt("Str1","Str2"));
        relevant.Add(() => ruleEchoIt("Str1"));
        relevant.Add(() => ruleChangeCase("Str1",true));

        return relevant;
    }

    public static String ruleEchoIt(String val)
    {
        return val;
    }

    public static String ruleChangeCase(String val, Boolean toUpper)
    {
        return (toUpper) ? val.ToUpper() : val.ToLower();
    }

    public static String ruleCombintIt(String val1, String val2)
    {
        return val1 + val2;
    }
}
```

This appears to satisfy all of your key requirements:

> 1) Need to be able to get the String return value

Satisfied by the `Func<string>`

> 2) Need to be able to set the actual parameter values of the function at the time I add the item to the list.

I'm glad you said set the parameter *values* - and not the parameter types. This would be much harder to accomplish as you cant store, for example, a `Func<string,string,string>` and a `Func<string, bool, string>` in the same collection easily.

> 3) Need to be able to handle cases (as shown) where each method being added to the list may have different parameters.

This is no problem as demonstrated so long as 2) above holds true.

Comment: Beat me to it, but yes, not sure what the commenters are getting so worked up about.

Comment: @jamiec - PERFECT! Thanks so much. Simple when you know how, but I didn't know how!!!